# SSDT Chart visible in Designer preview, but disappear when deployed to SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I have a report that shows a pie chart  and works fine in the Visual studio 2017 (SSDT), but disappears when the report is deployed to Report server.

Here is the report displayed in the designer[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see the design view and also the properties for the chart. When you run the deployed version, it could be getting pushed off to the side. Have you tried exporting that and see if it's anywhere in the export?

Comment: As StevenWhite said, it's most likely that the chart is pushed onto another page.IF this is the case, then there a few things you can do dependent on your report design. As we can't see your design I'll just point you in the right direction. Set the report level property "ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace" to True. Put the table in a rectangle.